# Batch file that replace letters without extension

Tags: batch-file, replace, translate

I'm trying to create simple batch file that replaces letters from latin to cyrillic in jpg file name but i dont know how to stop the batch file from changing extensions.

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=p"
Set "Replace=п"

For %%# in ("*.jpg") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Pause&Exit
```

This script changes name from p.jpg to п.jпg which is useless. 
Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you

Comment: So somehow you knew that the command modifier `n` is for the file name and `x` is for the file extension but did not realize you can use them individually.  I highly suggest you open up a cmd prompt and type: `for /?` The last section of the help file explains all the command modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

use the modifiers wisely:

```
...
For %%# in ("*.jpg") Do (
    Set "File=%%~n#"
     ECHO Ren "%%~f#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!%%~x#"
)
...
```

remove the `ECHO` if the output is what you need.